# Can I use asp.net identity to send a password reset email WITHOUT using entity framework to manage my users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net MVC app, which is partially using asp.net identity to manage users.  I say partially, because the only part of identity we are actually using is the part which generates a claim for the users cookie to show that they are logged in.  We are not using the parts of identity framework that require entity framework handle the saving and updating of user profiles, all that is done manually.

so, the task I have right now, is to rewrite the way that we allow users to reset their passwords.  We want to send the user a link that they click, with a code that they then verify, which allows them to set their new password.

I considered rolling my own cryptography for this, but that seems like generally, a bad idea, I am not a cryptography expert.  So, using the built in functions that asp.net identity provides seems like a good idea, but I am having serious troubles detangling EF from asp.net identity.  Let's take a look at some code I already have, and what I want to do.

My question: Is it possible to have asp.net identity generate the password reset tokens and codes, even if i choose not to use Entity Framework?

some nuget packages I am using:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core v2.2.1
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework v2.2.1 <-- not actually using it, just a dependency that it must be included
Microsoft.Owin" v3.0.1
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb v3.0.1
Microsoft.Owin.Security" v3.0.1
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies v3.0.1
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" v3.0.1
Owin v1.0
```

~\App_Start\AuthConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

namespace Arcteryx.Web
{
    public static class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void Config(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never,
                CookieName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationCookieName"] ?? "MyAppAuthentication",
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 24, 0, 0)
            };

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

~\Controllers\Account\AccountController.cs

```
// POST: /Account/LoginPost
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("{country}/{language}/account/login")]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult> LoginPost(LoginViewModel model, string ReturnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var account = new AccountLoginModel();
                Mapper.Map(model, account);

                account = _account.Login(account);
                if (account.LoginSuccess)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
                        return RedirectToAction("ViewProfile");

                    return Redirect($"~/{ReturnUrl}");
                }

                model.LoginErrorMessage = account.Message;
            }

            var loginViewModel = await LoginViewModel(ReturnUrl);


            Mapper.Map(model, loginViewModel);

            return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml", loginViewModel);
        }
```

_account in the file above is a DI injected instance of my account logic, some relevant parts of that file are here:
~\Account\AccountLogic.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Claim = System.Security.Claims.Claim;


public class AccountLogic : IAccountLogic
    {
        private readonly ISettingsProvider _settingsProvider;
        private readonly ICookieManager _cookieManager;
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly ILogging _logging;

        public AccountLogic(ISettingsProvider settingsProvider, ICookieManager cookieManager, IAuthenticationService authenticationService, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager, IUserService userService, ILogging logging)
        {
            _settingsProvider = settingsProvider;
            _cookieManager = cookieManager;
            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
            _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
            _userService = userService;
            _logging = logging;
            _credential = new NetworkCredential(_settingsProvider.SettingsModel.xx, EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(settingsProvider.SettingsModel.yy), settingsProvider.SettingsModel.zz);
        }

        public AccountLoginModel Login(AccountLoginModel account)
        {

            account = _authenticationService.Login(account, _credential);

            if (account.LoginSuccess)
            {
                IdentitySignin(account);
            else
            {   //we failed to login.  omitted error logging code here

            }
            return account;
        }

        public void UpdateClaim(AccountBaseModel account)
        { //this updates the users claim with everything we need to know about him
          //you could do the same by calling login, but then you would need his password
            IdentitySignin(account);
        }

        public bool Logout()
        {
            try
            {
                var user = _authenticationManager.User;
                if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    IdentitySignout();

                // Remove the login cookies
                _cookieManager.DeleteCookie("IsLogged");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //todo log some error here if we can't sign out.
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

private void IdentitySignin(AccountBaseModel account)
        {
            // create claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("Email", account.Email),
                new Claim("CustomerNumber", account.CustomerNumber.ToString()),
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            // sign the user in, basically this gives user cookies which cause him to be seen as authenticated
            _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = false, 
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
            }, identity);
        }
```

~AuthenticationService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using AutoMapper;
public class MyAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {

        public AccountLoginModel Login(AccountLoginModel account, NetworkCredential credential)
        {
            if (account == null || account.Email == null || account.Password == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("null arguments");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(credential.Domain) || credential.UserName == null || credential.Password == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Null web-service URL, username, password, and/or domain.");

            account.Message = "";
            bool returnValue;
            string WebIdent = string.Empty;

            //we need to send a DT in, gets us our user details.
            DataTable loginDt = null;

            using (var myservice = myfactory.Create(credential))
            {
                try
                {
                    returnValue = myservice .CustomerLogin(ref loginDt, account.Email, account.Password, ref WebIdent,
                        false);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    returnValue = false;
                    //log some error
                    account.Reason = AccountBaseModel.AccountFailureReason.CANTCONNECT;
                }

                if (returnValue)
                {
//omitted some code here, but basically, at this point, we have successfully logged in, by sending our username and password elsewhere to be validated.
                }

            return account;
        }
```

OK great, that's all working.  once a user logs in and we successfully validate his username and password, we give him a claims cookie and then we validate if he's logged in by that cookie using an [authorize] attribute on our controller actions.

OK, now what if i wanted to somehow:
-take a request from a user who has forgotten their password, they only know the email they signed up with.
-take that email they sent, generate, a cryptographically secure link, and an 8 digit code, and email it to the user (i really just need the codes, the emailing part i know how to do)
-have another mvc action that the user lands at, say /resetlink?id=CgT461JkKczIOQUvHK6o1KDs
-on this page, look up the link in database, see that we have it.  ask user for his code, see that they match.  send user to new page with 2 text boxes for enter new password and confirm new password.
-save new password to database.

I think I have the flow mapped out fairly clearly, and it's clear to me how to do this if i write my own randomly generated link strings that are sufficiently hard to guess.  it's also no problem to generate the random 8 digit codes.

my worry though, is that i will miss something in the implementation, and that this will be able to be hacked.  I looked into asp.net identity as an END TO END solution, but that is not an option for me right now (i have 6 sites running off of one userbase that lives in another, offsite db which I can only talk to using a soap web service).  so, i can't store users with my websites, they have to remain all in one place, and I can't use entity framework, at all.

The code i'd like to use is something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

```
// POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
        return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

in particular, this line: 
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

however.. I don't have a usermanager.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

How do i get a usermanger class?  Well, i just give it my EF db context..  but I don't have one of those either, nor any db i can read or write to that stores users..  In theory it would be done something like this: (in authconfig.cs)

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

^^  but yeah, i don't have an applicationdbcontext, that is an EF dependency.
furthermore, not sure what I am doing wrong, but my 'app' does not have any method like that, i get this: "IappBuilder does not contain a definition for CreatePerOwinContext"

so..  I am wondering, is this simply not possible, or what do I have to do to be able to generate these tokens?

Comment: You should consider shortening this down to what is necessary to solve your question. It seems a bit long-winded.

Comment: this is a fair point @Jake, the simple version of the question is the title: "Can I use asp.net identity to send a password reset email WITHOUT using entity framework to manage my users?"

my existing login implementation is given only for context